# Phone number regex: Brackets at the end

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to get phone numbers:

```
(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)
```

It works great but I need to include 3 digits enclosed with brackets at the end of the number:

```
0528907701     - Detected
(052)8907701   - Detected
52555552       - Detected
+9720523344433 - Detected
8907701(052)   - Not detected
8907701 (052)  - Not detected
```

I was trying to add this expression at the end: `\((\d{1,3}\)?)` But it prevents the other numbers from being detected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you append rules for what exactly to match, like number length etc.

Comment: @GCP The patterns `8907701(052)` and `8907701 (052)` should be good enough to get me the answer

Comment: Try [replacing `(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?` with `(?:[-.x ]*\(?(\d+)\)?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/pY2TYM/1). BTW, do you really need that many capturing groups?

Comment: Append `(?: ?\((\d{1,3})\))?`

Comment: `\d{7}(\s+)?\(\d{3}\)` will match those two patterns.

Comment: Just use [`\+?(?|(\d{3})|[-. (]+(\d{3})[-. )]+?)?(\d{3})(\d{2,4})(?|(\d{3})|[-. (]+(\d{3})[-. )]+?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/8NfemV/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following question it seems you confuse literal parenthese `\(` and group parenthese `(` in old regex or sed versions it could be inverted but generally.

- `(` is for a group,
- `\(` is for a literal parenthese, in a character set the backslash can be omitted.

so adding `( ?\(\d{1,3}\))?` at the end of your pattern should match. or for a non-capturing group `?:` must follow opening parenthese `(?: ?\(\d{1,3}\))?`

Answer (score 2):

Seems you mixed up the addition a little, correct pattern should be something similar to

```
(?: *\(\d{1,3}\))?
```

(I added the  `*` to account for the spaces in your last sample).